# Unity "member modifier "public" must precede the member type and name" error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im new to programming and I was trying to find out how I could program the movement but it kept saying I had an error

"member modifier "public" must precede the member type and name

and here is my code also if you can tell me how I could improve in learning coding

```
public class playerMoment : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

   public class ThirdPersonMoment : MonoBehavior {expected

            public Rigidbody Rb;
            
        public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 6f;

       




        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.getAxisRaw("vertical");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the pages linked therein. You will have a much better experience on Stack Overflow if you take the advice listed there.

Comment: Either get rid of or property define `expected` and it should be ok.

Comment: Also, it will greatly improve the readability (and therefore visual debugging) if you fix the indentation and whitespace, and use a consistent pattern for the opening braces (either put all the `{` on a new line, which is most common for c#, or put them all on the same line as the class/method declaration)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the code posted exhibits the error message specified by the question, with the assumption that we're working with the Unity game engine.

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line `public class ThirdPersonMoment : MonoBehavior {expected`

```
the name 'expected' does not exist in the current context.
```

That leads to the next error

```
Member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name
```

The compiler is unable to determine what `expected` is.

As you are also missing the semi-column  after `expected` the compiler assumes that                `expected public int Rb;` is a single instruction - complaining with the error you have provided -

The reason for that error is because `public` - the access modifier (read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers)) must come before anything else in the definition.

As pointed into the comments the code suffers from poor indentation - as you are new to programming and coding - I would strongly advise to learn some basic code writing skills and perhaps a bit more on C#.

Here is an example of the code:

```
    public class PlayerMoment
    {
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        public class ThirdPersonMoment
        {
            //expected changed into a comment
            public int Rb;
            public int Controller;
            public float Speed = 6f;

            // Update is called once per frame
            void Update()
            {
                float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("horizontal");
                float vertical = Input.getAxisRaw("vertical");
            }
        }
    }
```